"Issue Installing Laravel Homestead on Node.js - NVM Not Working
I'm encountering a problem while trying to install Laravel Homestead on Node.js. Specifically, the NVM (Node Version Manager) doesn't seem to be working as expected.
I've followed the installation instructions carefully, but when I attempt to install NVM, I'm facing some roadblocks. Has anyone else experienced this issue or found a workaround?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help.See image here 1
